# Connect SCOM 2016 Gateway Server to a Load balancer

Tags: scom

Evening Everyone,

I have been doing some research to see if a SCOM Gateway server can be configured to work with management servers behind a load balancers. In the reading and examples i see everyone pointing the gateway server directory to a management server.

If anyone has done this I would like to know what issues you faced.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achive?

scom management group is allready managing performance and workload in the resource pool for you... adding a middle NLB between the GW and MS seems very odd..

please be aware that if you evenatully will be using NLB. you need a physical NIC so that you will be able to use the Agent Deploy feature.